# Use CreateDataset to activate an empty dataset on a FDQuery in Offline mode

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-11-alexandria

I would like to add an Offline mode to an existing application, and to do so I need to be able to activate empty datasets on FDQuerys while in that Offline mode.

But when I try calling `CreateDataset` to activate those empty datasets it always tries to open the connection, which fails because the server is unavailable at the moment.

If I replace the Connection with a Dummy Connection, the CreateDatasets still fails because although it successfully opens the dummy connection it raises an exception that the original table has not been found, so my guess is that CreateDataset tries to retrieve metadata instead of using its persistent fields to create the empty dataset.

I try to remove the fetching of Metadata from the FDQuery.FetchOptions, but I can't make it work (I always get either a Server not found exception or a Table not found when I use a dummy connection). Example :

```
DataModule.Cn.Offline;
DataModule.Cn.FetchOptions.Items := [];
DataModule.Cn.FetchOptions.Cache := [];
DataModule.Cn.FetchOptions.AutoFetchAll := afDisable;
DataModule.QCustomer.Offline;
DataModule.QCustomer.CachedUpdates := True;
DataModule.QCustomer.FetchOptions.Items := [];
DataModule.QCustomer.FetchOptions.Cache := [];
DataModule.QCustomer.FetchOptions.AutoFetchAll := afDisable;
DataModule.QCustomer.CreateDataSet;
```

I know that I should use FDQuerys when the database is online, and FDMemtables when the database is offline, but I would like to be able to use in the new offline mode the hundreds of FDQuerys and code pointing to them that I already have.

So, do you know if it's possible to activate an empty dataset on a FDQuery while its connection is not available ?.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know that. I would use FDMemdata instead (They are like TClientDataSet)

Comment: @FreddieBell yes, I can do that, but it will force me to rewrite a huge part of the application, while it seems to me that I would be able to reuse what I already have if I'm just able to disable the retreiving of metadata.

Comment: You really need to do a critical analysis here. The benefits of using FDMemdata are going to outweigh the pain of rewrite long after that rewrite is done.

Comment: @FreddieBell I don't see any benefit rewriting the entire application to duplicate every dataset to FDMemTables. All the FireDAC datasets derive from the same FDDataset that implements the in-memory off-line mode, duplicating them to FDMemTables doesn't provide any additional benefit in that aspect. I just need to disable the retrieving of metadata for FDQuerys.